# Please how do i resolve the exception of null is not a subtype of String of type cast

Tags: flutter

```
I created a web service from Beeceptor to use to update my UI but resulted in an exception of null is not a subType of String of type cast.Please i need help
```

```
import 'package:my_api_practice/Endpoint/endpoint.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;

import 'UserDetails.dart';
import '';
part 'User.g.dart';

class User{
  String? name;
  String? imageUrl;
  String? time;
  List<UserDetails>?details;

  User({required this.details,required this.name,required this.imageUrl,required this.time});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json)=>_$UserFromJson(json);

  User.blank()
  :name='',
  imageUrl='',
  time='',
  details=[];

  static Future <List<User>>firstApi()async{
    http.Response response=await http.get(Uri.parse("https://xcompany.free.beeceptor.com/api/v1/users"));

    List<User>jsonitem=[];

    if(response.statusCode!=200){
   print(response.body);
  }
    for(var newItems in json.decode(response.body)){
      jsonitem.add(User.fromJson(newItems));
    }

    return jsonitem;
  }
}

<!--this is part of the User class-->


import 'package:my_api_practice/Endpoint/endpoint.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;

import 'UserDetails.dart';
import '';
part 'User.g.dart';

class User{
  String? name;
  String? imageUrl;
  String? time;
  List<UserDetails>?details;

  User({required this.details,required this.name,required this.imageUrl,required this.time});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json)=>_$UserFromJson(json);

  User.blank()
  :name='',
  imageUrl='',
  time='',
  details=[];

  static Future <List<User>>firstApi()async{
    http.Response response=await http.get(Uri.parse("https://xcompany.free.beeceptor.com/api/v1/users"));

    List<User>jsonitem=[];

    if(response.statusCode!=200){
   print(response.body);
  }
    for(var newItems in json.decode(response.body)){
      jsonitem.add(User.fromJson(newItems));
    }

    return jsonitem;
  }
}



<!--this is my webservice-->
```

[{
"0":{
"name":"Emmanuel Armoo",
"imageUrl":"https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-smiling-behind-wall-220453/",
"time":"2:00",
"description":"The is an ancient geek priest who discovered the whole fact to unlease the new technological advancement"
},

"1":{
"name":"Emmanuel Armoo",
"imageUrl":"https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-smiling-behind-wall-220453/",
"time":"2:00",
"description":"The is an ancient geek priest who discovered the whole fact to unlease the new technological advancement"
},

"3":{
"name":"Sister Armoo",
"imageUrl":"https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-smiling-behind-wall-220453/",
"time":"2:00",
"description":"The is an ancient geek priest who discovered the whole fact to unlease the new technological advancement"
},

"4":{
"name":"Kofi Armoo",
"imageUrl":"https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-smiling-behind-wall-220453/",
"time":"2:00",
"description":"The is an ancient geek priest who discovered the whole fact to unlease the new technological advancement"
}

}]

```
<!--this is my list of widget UI-->

import 'package:my_api_practice/models/User.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserList extends StatefulWidget{
  createState()=>_UserList();
}
class _UserList extends State<UserList> {
  bool isWaiting = false;
  List<User>users = [];


  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    ApiData();
  }
  ApiData() async {
    isWaiting=true;
    var jsonItem = await User.firstApi();
    setState(() {
      users = jsonItem;
      isWaiting=false;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('UserList'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          isWaiting ? LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: null,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
          ) : Container(
            child:Text('No UI to load')
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: users.length,
                itemBuilder: _itemTiles,)

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemTiles(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: _listImages(context, this.users[index]),
      title: _listTitles(context, this.users[index]),
      trailing: _listTimes(context, this.users[index]),
    );
  }

  Widget _listImages(BuildContext context, User user) {
    return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        child: Image.network(user.imageUrl!)
    );
  }

  Widget _listTitles(BuildContext context, User user) {
    return Text(user.name!);
  }


  Widget _listTimes(BuildContext context, User user) {
    return Text(user.time!);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to parse the response as if it's of the form

```
[{
    "name": "Emmanuel Armoo",
    "imageUrl": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-smiling-behind-wall-220453/",
    "time": "2:00",
    "description": "The is an ancient geek priest who discovered the whole fact to unlease the new technological advancement"
},
    ...
]
```

But it's

```
[{
    "0": {
        "name": "Emmanuel Armoo",
        "imageUrl": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-smiling-behind-wall-220453/",
        "time": "2:00",
        "description": "The is an ancient geek priest who discovered the whole fact to unlease the new technological advancement"
    },
    ...
 }]
```

I think you might be able to fix it by replacing

```
for(var newItems in json.decode(response.body)){
```

with

```
for(var newItems in json.decode(response.body)[0].values){
```

Although if possible I would fix the response to have it return like the first form

ADDITION:
I tried recreating a complete working app from your code and this is what I came up with, which seems to work fine:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: UserList()));
}

class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserList({super.key});

  @override
  State<UserList> createState() => _UserList();
}

class _UserList extends State<UserList> {
  bool isWaiting = false;
  List<User> users = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiData();
  }

  apiData() async {
    isWaiting = true;
    var jsonItem = await User.firstApi();
    setState(() {
      users = jsonItem;
      isWaiting = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('UserList'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          isWaiting
              ? const LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: null,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black),
                )
              : const Text('No UI to load'),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: users.length,
            itemBuilder: _itemTiles,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemTiles(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: _listImages(context, users[index]),
      title: _listTitles(context, users[index]),
      trailing: _listTimes(context, users[index]),
    );
  }

  Widget _listImages(BuildContext context, User user) {
    print(user.imageUrl);
    return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        child: Image.network(user.imageUrl!));
  }

  Widget _listTitles(BuildContext context, User user) {
    return Text(user.name!);
  }

  Widget _listTimes(BuildContext context, User user) {
    return Text(user.time!);
  }
}

class User {
  String? name;
  String? imageUrl;
  String? time;

  User({required this.name, required this.imageUrl, required this.time});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
        name: json['name'], imageUrl: json['imageUrl'], time: json['time']);
  }

  User.blank()
      : name = '',
        imageUrl = '',
        time = '';

  static Future<List<User>> firstApi() async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("https://xcompany.free.beeceptor.com/api/v1/users"));

    List<User> jsonitem = [];

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print(response.body);
    }
    for (var newItems in json.decode(response.body)[0].values) {
      jsonitem.add(User.fromJson(newItems));
    }

    return jsonitem;
  }
}
```

It has some clean up and I removed some warnings from your code but I didn't change anything drastically and it seems to work fine. Except that I changed `factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic>json)=>_$UserFromJson(json);` simply because I didn't have the implementation of `_$UserFromJson`. Also I noticed that your User mentions a `List<UserDetails>?details;` which I don't see in the api response so I just left that out. Notice also that the images don't work but that is simply because the `imageUrl` in your response doesn't link directly to an image but to a website with an image. Maybe this code helps you to find your actual problem because I don't think I can help anymore than this.

Comment: error cleared but couldnt update my UI.It returned a blank screen

Comment: @EmmanuelArmoo well, can't really judge why that is without seeing any of your UI code. It might be completely unrelated to this question

Comment: Please the i have updated it with the inclusion of the UI.The UI is at the end of the code

Comment: @EmmanuelArmoo I added some more to this answer. I hope it can help you